# Стоит ли обращать внимание на данные предупреждения об экспорте в DLL? С++

Tags: c++, dll

При попытке в своей dll библиотеке унаследоваться от `std::vector` постоянно сталкиваюсь с тем, что компилятор сильно ругается с ошибкой:

```
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\vector(1835): message : см. 
объявление "std::_Compressed_pair<std::allocator<ms::MemoryUnit>,std::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<_Ty>>,true>"
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Ty=ms::MemoryUnit
1>        ]
```

И, если более по-человечески:

```
C4251 std::vector<ms::MemoryUnit,std::allocator<ms::MemoryUnit>>::_Mypair: 
class "std::_Compressed_pair<std::allocator<ms::MemoryUnit>,std::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<_Ty>>,true>" 
должен иметь dll-интерфейс для использования клиентами class "
```

При попытке загуглить такую проблему нашел довольно много однотипных решений, которые заключались в добавлении такой строки:

```
template class YOUR_DLL_API_MACROS std::vector<YourType>;
```

Как я понял, это предварительное объявление с экспортом, но для меня это решение не сработало. Как правильно избежать данной ошибки?

Comment: Приведите выдачу компилятора полностью, пожалуйста. Других способов экспорта, кроме dllimort/dllexport, для классов нет. Возможно, вы экспортировали не все необходимое.

Comment: @Chorkov что именно вы хотите еще увидеть? Там огромная пачка таких же варнингов и мне кажется, что это не самая лучшая идея - копипастить все сюда

Comment: Сейчас я почитал о корне этой проблемы и понял, что выставлять любые std контейнеры в Dll - не лучшая идея. Но что делать с классами, которые наследуются от std контейнеров, если нужно методы std контейнера?

Comment: Это не предупреждение, а дополнение к предупреждению, текст которого расположен выше. (Спецификация с какими именно аргументами был инстанционирован шаблон, к которому относилось то предупрждение...) Нужен  текст от warninng, до следующего warning. В развернутом формате одно предпредупреждение иногда занимает несколько страниц.